# How to read the variable out of a click event function in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, function, global-variables

i am generating a value to a varible on a click event.

Which i need to use globally or out of it function event.

```
$("#Coil_Data tr").on('click', function (){
          var selectedcoilrowid = $(this).closest('tr').find('#Coil_ID').text()
          $('#selected_coil_id_title').text('Fan for the Coil ID : '+selectedcoilrowid)
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though variables should be avoided to be declared global, you can use the global object.

```
$("#Coil_Data tr").on('click', function (){
          global.selectedcoilrowid = $(this).closest('tr').find('#Coil_ID').text()
          $('#selected_coil_id_title').text('Fan for the Coil ID : '+global.selectedcoilrowid)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable outside of `click` event:

```js
let selectedcoilrowid = null;

$("#Coil_Data tr").on('click', function() {
  selectedcoilrowid = $(this).closest('tr').find('#Coil_ID').text()
  $('#selected_coil_id_title').text('Fan for the Coil ID : ' + selectedcoilrowid)
})

$('#check').click(function() {

  if (selectedcoilrowid != null) {
    console.log(selectedcoilrowid)
  } else {
    console.log('still is empty!')
  }
});
```

```css
#check {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Coil_Data">
  <tr>
    <td id="Coil_ID">19</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="selected_coil_id_title"></div>

<a id="check">Check Updated Variable</a>
```